# Why is it considered a direct modification of store values in NgRx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

Info about the snippet: state has a slice `educationList` which is an array of various educations (BS, MS, PhD). Each item in `educationList` array contains another array `description`, which contains info for projects, thesis etc.

The following is the snippet for deleting one of items of the `description` array:

```
case Actions.DELETE_ROLE: {
      let updatedEducationList = [...state.educationList];
      const targetIndex = updatedEducationList.findIndex((educationItem) => {
        return educationItem.id === action.payload.educationId;
      });
      let oldDescription = updatedEducationList[targetIndex].description;
      let newDescription = oldDescription.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload.roleIndex);
      updatedEducationList[targetIndex] = { ...updatedEducationList[targetIndex], description: newDescription };
      return { ...state, educationList: updatedEducationList };
    }
```

if the following line in the snippet,

```
updatedEducationList[targetIndex] = { ...updatedEducationList[targetIndex], description: newDescription }
```

is replaced with

```
updatedEducationList[targetIndex].description = newDescription;  //Edited this line
```

error takes place. The error is following.

```
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'description' of object '[object Object]'
    at educationListReducer (education-list.reducer.ts:110)
    at combination (store.js:303)
    at store.js:1213
    at store.js:383
    at ScanSubscriber.reduceState [as accumulator] (store.js:688)
    at ScanSubscriber._tryNext (scan.js:49)
    at ScanSubscriber._next (scan.js:42)
    at ScanSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at WithLatestFromSubscriber._next (withLatestFrom.js:57)
    at WithLatestFromSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

**But I think I already copied the state in the 1st line itself.**

```
let updatedEducationList = [...state.educationList];
```

What  am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let updatedEducationList = [...state.educationList];
// now updatedEducationList is a new array
// but its every element points to the related value in the current state.
// because it is not a deep clone.

const targetIndex = updatedEducationList.findIndex((educationItem) => {
    return educationItem.id === action.payload.educationId;
});
// now if you check state.educationList[targetIndex] === updatedEducationList[targetIndex] it will be true.
// Despite updatedEducationList === state.educationList is false.

let oldDescription = updatedEducationList[targetIndex].description;
// now it points to the current state.

let newDescription = oldDescription.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload.roleIndex);
// a new array of pointers to the current state items.

updatedEducationList[targetIndex].description = newDescription;
// wrong, because updatedEducationList[targetIndex] still points to the current state. and so does description.

updatedEducationList[targetIndex] = { ...updatedEducationList[targetIndex], description: newDescription };
// right, because it creates new object that doesn't point to current state anymore. only values of its keys.

return { ...state, educationList: updatedEducationList };
```

**ANSWER**

For objects and arrays containing other objects or arrays, copying these objects requires a deep copy. Otherwise, changes made to the nested references will change the data nested in the original object or array. In this case `description` is a nested object, therefore after the shallow copy, it still points to the same address in the memory as that from the original state

Comment: Shared the error. Edited the question for readability. description is an array of length 1 or 2.

Comment: is your question why you can't change `updatedEducationList[targetIndex].description = newDescription` directly? because code in the code snippet looks right.

Comment: yes. because, i think I am not modifying the state directly and I am returning the state also by `return { ...state, educationList: updatedEducationList };`

Comment: ah, I see. actually you do. I'll update the answer. 1 sec.

Comment: Done, below every line you can find an explanation what it does.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you find the address in the memory, the variable is pointing to ? Is it in Chrome DevTools ?

Comment: I read that just now that for  spread operator gives a shallow copy and for the deep clone we have to use JSON.stringify, because it is a nested object. Did you use this knowledge? I will love to see the memory. In C we can do that.

Comment: JSON.stringify is a hot fix, it changes all the pointers in the state even the data hasn't been changed, when the goal is to updated only changed branch like you do in your code. It requires more code compare to JSON.stringify, but it changes pointers only of updated path. As the result it helps memorized selectors to detect real changes and cause updates / re-renders only for updated data.